# Tough integral from a falling clock. $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{g^2t^2 + 2rgt\sin(t) + r^2} {\rm d}t$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, parametric, classical-mechanics, arc-length

A clock is under free fall for $60$ seconds and its second hand makes exactly one revolution during that period of time. It begins at rest with its second hand facing upwards. Given that the second hand has a length of $r>0$ and that the downward gravitational acceleration is some constant $g>0$, what is the total distance traveled by the tip of the second hand?

I came up with this little problem myself and got stuck at the end with a possibly impossible integral to evaluate. Here's a quick graphical interpretation of the problem: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ck8gxjughf

So, I started with the parametric equations representing the path of the tip of the second hand:

$$
\begin{align}
x = r\sin \left( \frac{\pi t}{30} \right), \quad
y = r\cos \left( \frac{\pi t}{30} \right) - \frac12 g t^2
&&\ &&\ \text{for } 0 \leq t \leq 60
\end{align}
$$

Then the total distance traveled can immediately be written as
$$
\begin{align} 
\int_0^{60} \sqrt{ \dot x ^2 + \dot y ^2} dt
& = \int_0^{60} \sqrt{ \left( \frac{\pi r}{30} \cos \left(\frac{\pi t}{30} \right) \right)^2 + \left( - \frac{\pi r}{30} \sin \left(\frac{\pi t}{30} \right) - gt \right)^2} {\rm d}t \\
& = \int_0^{60} \sqrt{ g^2t^2 + \frac{\pi r g}{15} t \sin \left( \frac{\pi t}{30} \right) + \left( \frac{\pi r}{30} \right)^2} {\rm d}t
\end{align}
$$

Which you can quickly approximate, giving a semi-satisfying answer to the problem, but I doubt has a closed-form solution in terms of $r$ and $g$.

Since having the revolution take $60$ seconds seems to make things messy, and that we're more interested in evaluating these integrals, consider instead
$$
\begin{align}
x=r \sin(t), \quad y = r \cos(t) - \frac12 gt^2 &&\ &&\ \text{ for } 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi
\end{align}
$$

> Are there any closed-form solutions of this integral for specific values of $r$ and $g$?
>   $$ 
> \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{g^2t^2 + 2rgt\sin(t) + r^2} {\rm d}t
> $$

Comment: As this is a physics problem, I'm tempted to examine the limits $r \ll 1$, for which the $r^{2}$ in the square root is suppressed and a Taylor expansion of the square root to first order leads to $2\pi^{2}g$. While $r \gg 1$ suppresses the $g^{2}t^{2}$ term and leads to $2\pi(r-g)$.

Mathematica is unable to evaluate the general case, nor the related integrals $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+t\sin t}\,\mathrm{d}t$ and $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{t^{2}+t\sin t}\,\mathrm{d}t$.

Answer (score 2):

So, the tip of the seconds hand will generate an **"accelerated" [cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid)**.

Being accelerated, it is no longer periodic, and the length will depend on the starting position.

The presence of the term $t \cdot \sin t$ under the square root seems to make very unprobable
that the integral might be evaluated in closed form.

Comment: Is any way to relate it to an unaccelerated one? (Intuitively there ought to be a way to take account of the "stretching", but I'm guessing that will be pretty messy too.)

Comment: well, that was my first tought also, but the stretching combines with rotation, making it no longer linear..

Comment: Yes, that's why I think the result would be horrible to deal with—it would have to take account of the slope of the un-stretched curve at every point.